# Circular dependency and dynamic assembly loading

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, circular-dependency

This is in AssemblyA

```
namespace AssemblyA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            Console.WriteLine(b.MultiplyTheSumByFactor(2, 3, 4));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public int Multiply(int left, int right)
        {
            return left * right;
        }
    }
}
```

This is in AssemblyB

```
namespace AssemblyB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        public int Sum(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        public int MultiplyTheSumByFactor(int left, int right, int factor)
        {
            // ClassA a = new ClassA(); // can't reference AssemblyA
            int sum = Sum(left, right);
            Type type = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().First();
            object a = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return (int)type.GetMethod("Multiply").Invoke(a, new object[] { sum, factor });
        }
    }
}
```

`AssemblyA` is a console application that references AssemblyB.

Why can't I reference `AssemblyA` from `AssemblyB`, though I can load `AssemblyA` through 
reflection and still call it's methods?

Obviously there is virtually no reason for wanting to do this, I'm just curious as to how the compiler / CLR works in order to allow this to work through reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because compiling an assembly requires linking to it's dependencies.  If the dependencies for A are not yet compiled (because they reference A) you end up with a chicken and egg problem.